# Jquery : inject response from AJAX posts into right div

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

This is driving me insane. Here's what I'm trying to do;

For every DIV on my page that has a class of 'gauge', I need to fire off a jquery Post request via Ajax, containing some parameters from a ViewModel (called 'params' in the code snippet below). The ID of each div is used in the request so the server knows which part of the page the request is for and so can respond with the right data. Then, when the response is received, the div is updated with the data in the response.

Here's the jquery code;

```
function updateGauges() {
    $(".gauge").each(
        function() {
            guid = this.id;
            var url = "/path/to/get_data/1/" + guid;
            $.post(url,JSON.stringify(params)).done(function(data){
                var score = data.score;

                var divToUpdate = $('#'+guid);
                divToUpdate.append(score);
            });
        }
    );
}
```

Suppose there are two divs in the page with a class of "gauge". What is happening is that the .each() loop is updating the variable "guid" before a response is received from the first ajax request is received. Hence, when the first ajax response arrives, the value of "guid" refers to the id of the second div, so the second div gets updated with data that was meant for the first div.

I have got this too work by setting

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});
```

but, of course, this degrades the user experience by forcing them to wait whilst all requests are issued and responses received.

Any help gratefully received! As you may have guessed, JavaScript ain't my strong point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `guid` a local variable so you'll get a different one saved in each closure.

```
var guid = this.id;
```

Comment: Thanks - simple when you know how!